# Controle Many LEDs with arduino

Tags: arduino, led

Can I control many LEDs with arduino like this project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5kLyt0sv0E ?
can the arduino resists with many LEDs ?
or should i use a rely or any other technic to keep LEDs  ?
i want to know about intensity. 
sorry i'm a newbie in english and electronics

Comment: Look into shift registers, that would be a nice start.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are talking about Charlieplexing, which means controlling many led's from just 4-5 pins of microcontroller. Have a look at this article :

http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-20-Leds-from-5-Arduino-pins-using-Cha/

and this one:

http://www.instructables.com/id/3-Arduino-pins-to-24-output-pins/

Answer (score 0):

An Arduino or most microcontroller can not directly control that many leds. You would need to use some led drivers. Dedicated led drivers, port expanders, or shift registers are the typical methods of achieving this. A typical Arduino can then control them as shown without issue.